# Shouldn't this Python function return 6 all the time?

Tags: python

I am new to Python and learning about functions. I came across the following function and at my wits end understanding how it works. It seems to me no matter the value of `b`, the answer should always be six but that isn't the case.

***CODE***

```
def mult(a, b):
    if b == 0:
        return 0
    rest = mult(a, b - 1)
    value = a + rest
    return value
print "3 * 2 = ", mult(3, 2)
```

My understanding of what happens

1. Since `b` is not 0 it proceeds
2. `rest` is assigned the value `3, 1` and it runs the function again
3. Since `b` is 1 and does to equate to 0, it proceeds to `rest`
4. `rest` is assigned the value `3, 0` and it runs the function again
5. Since `b` is now zero it returns the value 0
6. It then proceeds to `value` which has the value 3 + 3 as `a` had the value of 3 and `rest` had the value of 3 i.e. `(3,0)`
7. It returns the value 6

**But** if I assign `mult(3,4)`, it returns the value 12. Following my understanding, that isn't possible. Clearly, I am not understanding the logic flow. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: if you read carefully, it does `sum(a for x in range(b))` but recursively...

Comment: @JBernardo - I know it is recursion but where does `sum` come in and how does that work. How should I be reading the logic flow?

Comment: I've just translated the algorithm to a for loop. Try thinking backwards: The last iteration returns `0`, then `a`, then `a+a`... until `a+a+...+a` (number of parcels is `b`)

Answer (score 4):

The basic logic of this function is:

Let's (add `a` and subtract `1` from `b`) until `b == 0`. It might make more sense to you like this:

```
def mult(a, b):
    value = 0
    while b > 0:
        b = b - 1
        value = value + a
    return value
```

Only in stead of a while loop, your function keeps calling itself. I managed to contact `mult` himself and he was willing to explain:

> Hi, my name is mult and I'm a Recurser. Recursers are a common breed
>   in Computer Sciencia and we have a special feature; we can clone
>   ourselves. Sadly I was cursed with the inability to multiply. Still, I
>   wanted to live my dream as a multiplier and I did manage to find a way
>   to do it. Here's how:
>
> When you asks me to multiply `(a, b)`, I spawn one clone
>   and ask him `(a, b - 1)`. The clone repeats this process until
>   a clone is spawned that gets asked (`a`, `0`). When that happens
>   (there is a line of myself + `b` clones then), he answers to the
>   clone that spawned him: `0`. That clone in turn adds `a` to what he
>   was just told (the first time would be `0 + a`) and answers this to
>   the clone in front of him. This process repeats until I get answered
>   by the clone I spawned myself. I add `a` to that and return this as a final
>   answer to you!

```
def mult(a, b):
    # Should I ask a clone?
    if b == 0:
        # No! I reply 0 to my asker.
        return 0

    # Yes! I spawn a clone and ask him (a, b - 1) and wait for an answer to
    # store in 'rest'
    rest = mult(a, b - 1)

    # I take the answer and add to it the 'a' I was told
    value = a + rest

    # I return the value I calculated to my asker
    return value

print "3 * 2 = ", mult(3, 2)  # Here someone asks me (3, 2)
```

Comment: It is easier to understand however would like to my head around the logic flow of recursive functions. Never know when I may come across a complex one

Comment: I added a section on the recursive logic of the function, I hope this makes it all grockable

Answer (score 3):

You can instrument your code to make it easier to see what is happening

```
def mult(a, b):
    print "mult(%s, %s)"%(a, b)
    if b == 0:
        return 0
    rest = mult(a, b - 1)
    value = a + rest
    print "returns %s"%value
    return value
print "3 * 2 = ", mult(3, 4)
```

---

```
3 * 2 =  mult(3, 4)
mult(3, 3)
mult(3, 2)
mult(3, 1)
mult(3, 0)
returns 3
returns 6
returns 9
returns 12
12
```

Due to the recursion, the print statements are nested

ie. `mult(3, 0)` returns 3, `mult(3, 1)` returns 6, and so on

Answer (score 2):

1. `mult()` is called with `3, 2` (this is call #1)
2. which calls `mult()` with `3, 1` (this is call #2)
3. which calls `mult()` with `3, 0` (this is call #3)
4. which returns 0 (because `b` was zero) to call #2
5. call #2 now returns 3 + that 0 to call #1
6. call #3 now returns 3 + 3

Basically, each invocation is going to increment the `a` value by `a`, recursively delving into istelf `b` times. So, adding 3 to itself 4 times will yield 12.

Answer (score 2):

Your logic is right until bullet 5. Then at 6 you skip some steps.
This is a recursive function. It is easier to understand it by drawing the tree of events on paper, but lets resume your logic first:

mult(3,4):

```
 1. a = 3, b = 4
 1. rest = mult(3, 3)
 2. a = 3, b = 3
 2. rest = mult(3, 2)
 3. a = 3, b = 2
 3. rest = mult(3, 1)
 4. a = 3, b = 1
 4. rest = mult(3, 0)
 5. a = 3, b = 0
 5. return 0
 4. value = 3 + 0
 4. return 3
 3. value = 3 + 3
 3. return 6
 2. value = 3 + 6
 2. return 9
 1. value = 3 + 9
 1. return 12
```

In the example above, each number at the beginning of the line represents the step in the recursion. It starts at step 1, goes until step 5 in this case, and then returns 1 by 1 until step 1 again with your final answer.

The function implements the concept of multiplication through sums. For example, 3 * 4 is the same of adding the number '4' three times.

Comment: Thanks. I lost you at where you start the sum of `3 + 0`. Why does it reverse in the addition i.e. 4,3,2,1? Also does (3,0) mean `3*0` and so forth and hence `value` is `3 + (3*0)`

Comment: The part where I start value = 3 + 0; is reaches b = 0, returns 0 on rest, and then does value = a + rest;
Then, the just calculated value return to the previous rest and do again value = a + rest; and so forth.
As I said before, recursion is something tricky.
Try looking for a video of a teacher doing it in youtube. If you find one where he draws the recursion tree you will get it :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to visually see how the recursion works:

```
COUNTER = 0

def mult(a, b):
    global COUNTER

    COUNTER+=1
    print " "*COUNTER + "Called with", a,b

    if b == 0:
        return 0
    rest = mult(a, b - 1)
    value = a + rest

    COUNTER -= 1
    print " "*COUNTER, "Value:", value 

    return value

print "3 * 4 = "
print mult(3, 4)
```

Output

```
3 * 4 = 
 Called with 3 4
  Called with 3 3
   Called with 3 2
    Called with 3 1
     Called with 3 0
     Value: 3
    Value: 6
   Value: 9
  Value: 12
12
```

You can see how the call stack goes all the way down to the bottom (b==0), and then returns values back up the chain to the top.